# Load data in Qlik Sense Server with token's pagination

Tags: node.js, qliksense

I have an express server who send data in JSON to Qlik Sense Server. My problem is, I got a timeout (30 secs) and I can not change that (I don't have access) cause of a lot of row.

So I send to Qlik 10k row with a "continuationToken" and after that, I need to take the "continuationToken" to send back to my server.

How can I do that?

I specify that I use a REST connector using method GET and I don't have access to change anything on the connector (preconfig by qlik sense)

Comment: Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580152/10972959

Comment: It works ! thy so much

Comment: great! please vote for my answer there