# How can do API call in a Loop and consolidate its result in a Temp table?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I want to do something as follows in Qlikview.

Need to call the API in the loop till the resp becomes empty array. Also need to append next value in the URL from the response.

```
TempTable:
Let next = '';
Let apiUrl = https://myapiurl;
do {
  resp = Calling my API (apiUrl + next);
  push resp.data to TempTable
  next = resp.next;
} (while resp.data.length > 0);
```

Target is I want a consolidate output of the API calls.

Suppose if we can't do it with TempTble, is there any other ways?

Comment: are you using QV rest connector?

Comment: Yes we are using rest connector

Comment: have you watched this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqwNU_pnFt4&t=139s

Comment: Hi EldadT, I watched this video just now. Already connected with API. My requirement is getting data based on some next link which contains key for next set of records and limit for pagination. That link will be available in each response to get next set of records

Comment: In that video it show how to use that "next" link...

Comment: Hi please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580152/10972959 it takes next link and call sub recursively again. Root table is dropped and data is auto-concatenated t new table