# Reading data using REST in Qlik Sense

Tags: rest, pagination, qliksense

I am trying to consume data from a REST endpoint in Qlik Sense and the endpoint has large volume of data that is to be extracted using cursors.

The data set looks like below in the rest response.

```
{
   "users": [...],
   "next_cursor": "1234",  # the key for the extra result set
}
```

The problem I have is, when I create the REST connection in Qlik Sense the next_cursor does not seem to appear for me to be able to read it.

I can only read the contents of users. How can I read the next_cursor data.

Please help share some info on how this can be achieved.

I am using Qlik Sense Feb 2021 P6

Comment: please provide bigger example of data and share your code to load json. You can also try to look to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552470/qliksense-rest-offset-pagination-using-loop/54580152#54580152 specially part about full qualified keys. If it helps please tick there :-)